# Facebook Reel video does not play when using Puppeteer on Node.js

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Currently, I'm trying to access Facebook Reels using Puppeteer on Node.js. However, the video is not playing. The template of the video is displayed, but the video section shows a black screen, like this:

[image: facebookreel]

I'm using Puppeteer version 20.3.0. How can I make the video play? Here is my code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const testRun = async () => {
    const launchOptions = {
        headless: false,
    };
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto("https://www.facebook.com/reel/1573966706275454", {
        waitUntil: "networkidle2",
        timeout: 0,
    });
};

testRun();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browser instance that Puppeteer launches doesn't have codecs to play video.

You should define path to your default browser instance that has them.

Example on Mac:

```js
const launchOptions = {
      headless: false,
      executablePath: '/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome',
    };
const browser = await puppeteer.launch(launchOptions);
```

Comment: thannk you! it works!

Comment: the latest version of CfT should have codecs. See https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/chrome-for-testing/issues/18#issuecomment-1726552383 Chrome for Testing (CfT) is the Chrome flavour that recent versions of Puppeteer download by default.